# L2 constructions of Brownian motion that fails the continuity

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

The basic idea of $L^2$ constructions of Brownian motions is as follows. Let $\{\xi_k\}$ be a sequence of iid Gaussian random variables. Let $\{\phi_k\}$ be a complete orthonormal basis system in $L^2([0,1])$. The idea is to show that the limit

$$
\lim_{N\to \infty} B^N(t)
$$

is a Brownian motion, where

$$
B^N(t) = \sum^N_{k=1} \xi_k \, \langle \mathbb{1}_{[0,t]}, \phi_k \rangle.
$$

It can be shown that the aximos of the Brownian motions always hold **except for the continuity axiom**. In literature, in order to prove the continuity axiom, one has to spefically choose the basis $\{\phi_k\}$, for example, the Haar and Schauder basis.

My question: is it so that the continuity actually hold for all choices of system $\{\phi_k\}$? If not, is there an example of $\{\phi_k\}$ such that the continuity does **not** hold?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Kolmogorov continuity theorem tells us that if $X$ is a stochastic process satisfying $\mathbb{E}[|X_t-X_s|^{\gamma}] \le c|t-s|^{1+\varepsilon}$ for some positive constants $\gamma,c,\varepsilon$ and all $t,s \in [0,1]$, then there exists a continuous process $\tilde X$ that is indistinguishable from $X$, i.e. $\mathbb{P}(\tilde X_t = X_t \text{ for all }t \in [0,1]) = 1$.  Since $\mathbb{E}[|X_t-X_s|^{\gamma}] \le c|t-s|^{1+\varepsilon}$ is implied by $X_t - X_s \sim N(0,t-s)$, $B(t)$ satisfying all of the axioms except continuity implies $B(t)$ is continuous up to indistinguishability.  Therefore, regardless of the choice of $\{\phi_k\}$ used in the construction, the limit is continuous up to indistinguishability.

Comment: You mean whatever the $\{\phi_k\}$ we choose, there always exists a Brownian motion whose restriction is $\lim_N B^N(t)$?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by restriction here, but yes, we can always find a Brownian motion $W$ satisfying $W(t) = \lim_N B^N(t)$ for all $t$ a.s.  The slight problem is that $\lim_N B^N(t)$ is an a.s. limit, so you could also define a process $B(t) := \lim_N B^N(t)$ that is different on some null sets.